# Resigning from position

Tags: resignation, work-life-balance

I was unemployed for a long time and became quite pessimistic. Then I just applied for a suitable position and surprisingly got hired.

Because I used to live independent (waking and sleeping late) and had no sense of working habit, this new situation disturbs me. I do not like to wake up early. I am aware that working life needs it at some point but because of long distance transportation I really have push myself every morning. I come home relatively late and have no time - one or two hours - and then need to sleep again.

I am not sure these are good reasons to resign.

Edit:

- It feels wrong to resign after not having had a job for a long time. Will such a drastic change demolish my career?
- Is "Carpe Diem" an acceptable approach for professional life at very early stages?
- What are the appropriate ways to motivate myself/overcome unwillingness in this case?

---

Edit #2:

'Carpe Diem' - What I meant is focus more on personal welfare and social life than career (60/40 ratio and more I accept as carpe diem)

'very early stages' - I have couple of years of experience in industry but it is less then 10 years and I am kind of young. So I am highlighting it is not well-earned tiredness and unwillingness after very long career path.

Comment: I think it is up to you. You want to be unemployed or have a normal work life.

Comment: Could you possibly move closer to the office?  Long transit sucks ..

Comment: btw it's normal to take some time to adjust to work hours again after a long time not working.  It gets better after a few weeks ... coffee helps ..

Comment: This is the type of decision you can and should be doing for yourself. Nobody can determine for you whether you have enough hate for waking up early in the morning enough to hand in your resignation. Nobody can determine for you how important it is to you that you have an easier time landing the next job either.

Comment: @Coner I have heavily edited your question in an attempt to make it more on-topic. You can revert the edit if you want to. I suggest you [edit] again and explain what you mean with the 'Carpe diem' question. I understand its meaning but it sounds like a conclusion you have already drawn (also: why "at very early stages"?). I have also removed your opinion about the comments. It does not belong in the question and irony/sarcasm towards people commenting will not help you. They only comment to help you to get issue clearer, that can occasionnally mean things you do not 'want' to hear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

This is the reality of life for most people.  Without knowing what you do, I don't know if you could find a job working later (or closer to home), but having been long term unemployed, surely the idea of quitting (and losing money, I assume you earn more than you'd get as unemployed) is worse than keeping going.

So the answer is NO, it's not wise to take this action.  By all means look for another job, but do that while remaining in your current one.

Answer (score 9):

Quite frankly, you have 3 options:

Option 1 - Keep working, realise that as an adult you need to have a job to support yourself and you need to follow the rules of that job (i.e. getting up when you have to work). Consider moving closer to your job to shorten your commute time, but realise that you will always have to get up with the rest of the world and not just sleep as long as you like.

Option 2 - Work like this for a few years until you have developed your skills and then become a freelancer, you can work your own hours but will still need to be contactable during normal hours.

Option 3 - Be unemployed again, have no job and be unable to support yourself.

So yeah, if you want to be a self-supporting successful adult, you can't just quit every job because you're tired in the mornings. *We're all* tired in the mornings.